# When the difference of the average of the first $n+1$ sequences and the average of the first $n$ converges, does the average converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider a sequence $a_n$ in a compact set. We can define the average of the sequence by:

$$
\bar{a}_n=\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}{n}
$$

Assume $|\bar{a}_{n+1}-\bar{a}_n| \leq \frac{C}{n}$. Then $\bar{a}_{n+1} - \bar{a}_n$ converges to zero; however, $\bar{a}_n$ itself may not converge.

My question is: Assume $|\bar{a}_{n+1}-\bar{a}_n| \leq \frac{C}{n^2}$. Does $\bar{a}_n$ converge? (My intuition says yes since $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, but $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges) How do I show it? Or is it NOT true?

Comment: Every sequence $(x_n)$ such that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leqslant y_n$ where $\sum y_n$ converges, does converge. Can you show this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sequence $\bar a_n$ does converge by the very reason you state. We have for $m>n$ 
$$ |\bar a_m-\bar a_n|\le |\bar a_m-\bar a_{m-1}|+\ldots +|\bar a_{n+1}-\bar a_n|\le \frac C{(m-1)^2}+\ldots+\frac C{n^2}<C\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac 1{k^2}$$
From the convergence of $\sum \frac1{k^2}$ we know that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that the right hand side is $<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$, in other words, the sequence  $\bar a_n$ is Cauchy. (Thus instead of compactness, we need only completeness)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your question has nothing to do with every element being an average. Provided that: $$\left|b_{n+1}-b_n\right|\leq\frac{C}{n^2}\tag{1}$$
we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\left|b_{n+M+1}-b_n\right| &\leq& C\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{(n+M)^2}\right)\\&\leq&C\left(\frac{1}{n(n-1)}+\ldots+\frac{1}{(n+M)(n+M-1)}\right)\\&\leq&\frac{C}{n-1}\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence $\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence.